# Android : CalledFromWrongThreadException even when used runOnUIThread

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-asynctask

I'm building an application which sends login data and authenticates by communicating with the php files in my localhost (referring to this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/). I tried it like the tutorial says (in the main thread) but it gives a NetworkOnMainThreadException. But when I try the following inside an AsyncTask, it gives a CalledFromWrongThreadException even when I'm using runOnUIThread.

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = etPass.getText().toString();
            UserFunctions userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
            final JSONObject json = userFunctions.loginUser(username, password);

            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {

                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                    if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {
                        // user successfully logged in
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                errorTxt.setText("");
                                //if (pDialog.isShowing())
                                    //pDialog.dismiss();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(
                                        getApplicationContext(),
                                        AgentHome.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                } else if(json.getString(KEY_ERROR) != null) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //if (pDialog.isShowing())
                                //pDialog.dismiss();
                            errorTxt.setText("Invalid username or password");
                        }
                    });

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Edit : I put the errorTxt.setText("") inside the runOnUIThread but still it gives the following errors

```
02-11 10:27:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(4957): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-11 10:27:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(4957): Process: collector.lbfinance, PID: 4957
02-11 10:27:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(4957): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-11 10:27:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
02-11 10:27:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
02-11 10:27:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
02-11 10:27:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
02-11 10:27:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
02-11 10:27:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-11 10:27:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-11 10:27:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-11 10:27:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(4957): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-11 10:27:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at collector.lbfinance.MainActivity$GetPassword.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:108)
02-11 10:27:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at collector.lbfinance.MainActivity$GetPassword.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
02-11 10:27:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
02-11 10:27:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-11 10:27:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: what is line 108 MainActivity.java

Comment: if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null). Just after the try

Comment: json is null pls check it

Comment: It also gives "Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null". I have no idea what's wrong here

Comment: log the json that you get from server

Comment: Log.d("JSON", json.toString()); should do it right? But there's nothing in the logcat. Still the same set of errors

Comment: that means there is no response. check how you get the json. fix that. else you will end up getting the same errors

Answer (score 1):

`errorTxt.setText("");` is not on the ui thread. You can't update ui from a background thread.

Also you can get the text from edittext on button click and pass it as a param to `doInBackground` directly.

Asynctask has `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` which are invoked on the ui thread. You should consider updating ui in those methods. Do all your background computation in `doInbackground`. I don't see the need for `runOnUiThread`.

Comment: @ThahzanMohomed i am saying you don't need `runOnUiThread`. Even if you have used it `errorTxt.setText("");` is not ui thread not inside the run method of `runOnUithread`.

Comment: Checked. But still getting error. See the edit please

Comment: @ThahzanMohomed you have a `NUllPointerException`. what is line 108 `MainActivity.java`. you have a different problem

Answer (score 0):

Check AsyncTask lifecycle. You can execute code on UI thread in  constructor and following methods: onPreExecute, onProgressUpdate(with corresponding publishProgress call) and onPostExecute. Be sure to place your UI changing code to one of those

Answer (score 0):

Please use hanlder and pass your response to handler, it will work.

A Handler allows you to send and process Message and Runnable objects associated with a thread's MessageQueue. Each Handler instance is associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue. When you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it -- from that point on, it will deliver messages and runnables to that message queue and execute them as they come out of the message queue.

[Handler Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

[Handler example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

First of all You are Setting text in background Thread Which is wrong & it gives u exception so first remove that `errorTxt.setText("");` from doInBackground & set that in PreExecute Or PostExecute or In Some another UI thread But not in Background. And No need to use this

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {}
```

Thread, If you write your code in Background Async Task then also it will work same.
hope this helps.